# sorting array element using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

i need program in which you enter words via the keyboard or file and then they come out sorted by length using javascript

Comment: why don't you write it?

Answer (score 6):

You should take a look at the [array sort method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp). You can use it and pass in a function that performs the sorting based on whatever criteria you like.

Answer (score 4):

The [sort method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) takes a function as a parameter:

```
var a = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];

a.sort(function(a,b){
  return a.length - b.length
});
// returns ["one", "two", "four", "five", "three"]
```

Comment: I was about to write the actual function. You beat me to it. +1

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example on how to [Sort an Array](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) in Javascript

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
array.sort(function(el1,el2){
  return el1.length - el2.length
});
```